# Switch between Realm databases at runtime?

Tags: android, realm

In my case, a user can be logged in with multiple accounts at once (like Gmail etc.)  and for every logged in account, I have a different Realm configuration.

In case user changes account (pulls out drawer, selectes a new account), what's the best way to change Realm configuration to display and handle data that is associated with the new account from now on?

Comment: Use a different Realm instance in your queries

Comment: I've thought about this but this is not a preferable option in my case. I'd like to change default Realm instance when accounts change. But that doesn't instantly refresh all queries.

Comment: Well, no, you have to query your queries from the new Realm instance and replace the old ones.